# WPF - PRISM After view activation, validation drops

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

To switch view in WPF/PRISM I use activate/deactivate on the region.

I'm having a base class with IDataErrorInfo implemented, when my module loads my view, the validation instantly happens. When I switch towards an other view and back, the validation is gone.. No tooltips or markings that the fields contain errors. The only thing that is stopping is my safeguard check on my "submit"-button.

Not very user-friendly I suppose.

So I'm currently looking towards a way to re-evaluate the view after activation...

[Code on request]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allways clear the Views and add them again to the RegionManager on navigation. Usually that is related to custom code, and it's hard to pinpoint others errors, it can be something you're getting from the container that is a singleton, or when you're re-using the ViewModel you're not validating anymore, etc.

The clear all views in the RegionManager region then activate again is the brute force solution that usually works, the good practice solution is somewhere between taking care of that in the ViewModel or writing your own `RegionBehavior` and adding it to Prism in the Bootstrapper.

You have some examples of `RegionBehavior` classes on both of Prism's Reference Implementations.

Comment: I have tried your first suggestion, but the problem is that my ViewModel is attached to an event on a singleton class. Removing the view and adding it again will create a second attachment to that event and I don't want the event to occur more then once. It worked as long as I didn't need to fire that specific event..

Comment: That's an easy one to resolve. Before removing all the views just unsubscribe to that event. Again, by writing your own RegionBehavior you can do this on the Attach / Detach action on the RegionManager, which would be the best way to go.

Comment: I resolved it by attaching my event on the execution of the my submit-command.. The event is fired when my server responses.. I bump my head for not getting to this point earlier -.-
Thanks for the advise on RegionBehaviors

Comment: Took me a full week to build a good Prism infrastructure for my first application using it, had to deal with a lot of issues, most of them aren't even documented by "googling" them, so I try to help other peers going through the same process! Good luck with your implementation.